# Firebase/JS - Make a JavaScript fire before loading the page?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm currently making a JavaScript script which fetches the User's Data from the Realtime DB

```
/* Fetch User Data from Firebase */

function userInfo() {
    var username;
    var usertype;
    var barangay;

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      if (user) {
        var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
        return firebase.database().ref('/users/' + userId).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
        username = (snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().name) || 'Unknown';
        barangay = (snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().barangay) || 'Unknown';

        document.getElementById('fullname').innerHTML = username; //Sets the username in the Webpage. 
        });
      } else {
        window.location.replace("../index.html"); //redirect
      }
    });
  }
  window.onload = userInfo();
```

The `window.onload = userInfo();` is the code i'm currently using to make the script fire on page load, but this results in a delay of updating the data in the innerHTML. *(Example: the `<p id='fullname'>`'s content is "USERNAME", and will be updated with the "user's name" fetched from the script.)*. I have tried putting the JS files on top of the page, with the same result.

My question would be, is there any way to make this script fire **FIRST**, before the page loads? Or is there a more efficient way to handle this script?

Answer (score 1):

In theory, the request will fire (asynchronously) before the DOM is loaded if you place the script in the head tag. However, you don't know how long it will take before the request is completed. It might even fail.

My suggestion would be to give some sort feedback to the client that the information is loading (i.e. show a progress indicator). There are countless of articles written on how you can approach this.

Remember that you don't have to show any content before the information is retrieved. That's completely up to you.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing async and sync functions...I don't know your architecture but assuming that you have only this page, just wrap a inline script and it should work, without window.onload

```
<script>
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      if (user) {
        var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
        return firebase.database().ref('/users/' + userId).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
        username = (snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().name) || 'Unknown';
        barangay = (snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().barangay) || 'Unknown';

        document.getElementById('fullname').innerHTML = username; //Sets the username in the Webpage. 
        });
      } else {
        window.location.replace("../index.html"); //redirect
      }
    });
</script>
```

the problem with this approach is that you page won't load until the promise is resolved and this could take long (and also fails) which is not good for your user experience. As already mentioned you have different ways of addressing this issue, one of them is [Web Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)